# How to create a default binding for an InputAction?

Tags: unity, input

When I have an `InputAction` in a Unity component, like this:

```
[SerializeField] InputAction jump = new InputAction(type: InputActionType.Button);
```

I can add one or more bindings to that action through the Inspector. This has the  disadvantage that other people using my component cannot just use it as-is - they have to manually add bindings.

Alternatively,  I can add bindings in my code, like this:

```
private void Awake() {
    jump.AddBinding("<Keyboard>/space");
}
```

Then anyone can use my component out-of-the-box. However, this binding cannot be changed through the inspector.

Is there a way to set a "default binding" for an InputAction, that is available for anyone using the component without any need for a manual action, but still can be modified through the inspector?

This is possible for other input types, e.g. when I write:

```
[SerializeField] float maxSpeed = 10.0f;
```

it gives a default value that can be modified through the inspector. Is the same possible for an InputAction?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html), there is a constructor that takes the binding path as an optional string argument. If you use it in the declaration, I would expect it to do what you want. Something like 

`[SerializeField] InputAction jump = new InputAction(type: InputActionType.Button, binding:"<Keyboard>/space");`

Comment: @PepeOjeda Thanks! This works for a simple binding, but I could not make it work for composite binding, such as `moveHorizontal.AddCompositeBinding("1DAxis")       .With("Positive", "<Keyboard>/rightArrow").With("Negative", "<Keyboard>/leftArrow");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for `OnValidate`

```cs
public class DefaultInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputAction jump;
    public InputAction moveHorizontal;

    void OnValidate() {
        if (jump == null) {
            jump = new InputAction(type: InputActionType.Button);
        }
        if (jump.bindings.Count == 0) {
            jump.AddBinding("<Keyboard>/space");
        }
        if (moveHorizontal == null) {
            moveHorizontal = new InputAction(type: InputActionType.Value);
        }
        if (moveHorizontal.bindings.Count == 0) {
            moveHorizontal.AddCompositeBinding("1DAxis").With("Positive", "<Keyboard>/rightArrow").With("Negative", "<Keyboard>/leftArrow");
        }
    }
}
```

`OnValidate` gets called in the Unity editor in a number of cases:

- When this component is first added to an object
- When a value on this component is changed in the Inspector
- When the C# assembly containing this script is reloaded
- When entering play mode

...but it's not called in game builds, so it doesn't add any runtime overhead to your game the way an `Awake`, `OnEnable`, or `Start` method does.

You'll notice I chose not to use field initializers on these actions, but instead check in `OnValidate` if they're `null` and populate them if so. The reason for that is that `InputAction` is a reference type, so constructing a `new` instance of it involves a memory allocation and garbage collection book-keeping, in addition to the work done by its constructor. This happens even if the default initialized value later gets overwritten by a serialized value the designer provided in the inspector, so you waste cycles on an allocation for a throwaway object. This isn't a problem for value types like numbers/vectors/etc. because they don't need separate GC tracking, but for more complex types that do more work on construction, it's good to avoid redundant initialization.

Doing it this way does the work of building and inserting the default value only if necessary, and only ever at edit time, while still giving you the freedom to make the default binding logic as complex as you need. You can replace the defaults with your own versions in the Inspector and they'll be preserved - the code only restores default bindings when no binding is present. And at runtime, it's just as efficient as a version that was keyed-in by hand.

Comment: Works great, thanks!